# Dynamically set select2 options with formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Select2 v4.0 lets you add options to the dropdown dynamically by creating new `Option` objects and appending them.  How can you dynamically add data which has more than just an id and text?

More specifically, if the select2 uses the `templateResult` configuration to style data with more than just plain text then adding `Option`s is too restrictive.  This callback only works with the library's own data format.

```
$('#select2').select2({
    templateResult: function(data) {
        return data.text + ' - ' + data.count;
    }
});
$('#select2').append(new Option('Item', 1, false, false));
```

I'd like to add more complex data when the dropdown is opened and template the results.

I've tried some ugly workarounds, such as

```
var opt = new Option('Item', 1, false, false);
opt.innerHTML = '<div>Item</div><div>Count</div>';
```

But the HTML gets stripped and select2 displays plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library's maintainer states there is not going to be any support for this feature, as reported in [a closed Github issue](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2830) .  The only reasonable workaround I've found is to re-initialize the element after it's populated:

```
function initSelect2(data) {
  var select = $('#select2');
  select.select2({
    templateResult: function(data) {
      return data.text + ' - ' + data.count;
  });
  if (data.length) {
    select.data('loaded', 1);
    select.select2('open');
  } else {
    select.on('select2.opening', fillSelect2);
}

function fillSelect2() {
  var select = $('#select2');
  if (select.data('loaded')) {
    return;
  }
  var data = [];
  var data.push({id: 1, text: 'One', count: 1});
  var data.push({id: 2, text: 'Two', count: 2});
  var data.push({id: 3, text: 'One', count: 3});
  initSelect2(data);
}

initSelect2();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just using the standard html/jQuery and customize whatever you need.

`$('#select2').append("<option value='"+ id +"'>" + text+ "</option>");`

Comment: select2 seems to strip the tags with this solution and only give plain text results.  It won't let you format the options any further.